# How to install OSGeo4W libraries in older version of QGIS (2.16)?

Tags: qgis, osgeo4w

I am trying to install older version of QGIS (2.16) with OSGeo4W. But from the latest OSGeo4W Setup i can choose only 2.18 or 2.14 version. I want to install few libraries that are provided by OSGeo4W setup file to older version of QGIS. How can i do it?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an answer. Once older version of QGIS is installed on PC the OSGeo4W setup file is located in this location

C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.16\bin

Then set location to C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.16 and proceed.

[image: Set loc]

Inside there i can keep all previous installed files and just add new libraries to existing version of QGIS.

[image: Keep]

Using this method version of Qgis won't be updated.

Comment: That would be a previous stand alone install.

Comment: Nope. When you keep all the files that are already install you won't change Qgis version.

Answer (score 8):

OSGEO4W only offers the current point release, the one before (currently 2.18.3), and the dev and LTR version.

For older Windows versions, you can still grab the standalone installer from http://download.osgeo.org/qgis/windows/. It will not interfere with or delete the OSGEO4W installation you already have.